# Referencing External CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a website to host an application that I made and I am using IntelliJ IDEA IDE to do it.
I have two html pages and a css file:

```
/index.html
/projects/somepage.html
/css/styles.css
```

So, in both html pages, I want to reference the css file, so I have this in both html pages:

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I thought this would work, but no, neither pages have any styling.

If I view the source of an html page, and click to see where its trying to get the css file, it's looking at C:/css/styles.css.

I'm kind of new to developing websites from scratch, maybe the path is wrong slightly? I can get it to work if I take styles.css out of the folder and reference it as just "styles.css" in index.html and as "../styles.css" in somepage.html but I don't want to have to use different paths for different pages.

Is this a problem with my IDE? there is a file that IntelliJ IDEA created when I made the project called Website.iml that might be relevant. This is what is inside of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Although, I don't really know how the IDE would have any effect on it at all since it just helps create the code and the file structure is exactly the same if I didn't use the IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run a development server when you're building your application, because it will behave differently when on a server vs just as files on your local machine. For instance, right now the path is wrong because it is searching for the css/style.css in the root directory, which on your machine is the C:/ drive. When you put this onto a server, it will work perfectly because all your files *will* be in the root directory.

Running a development server is super easy, there are a million ways to do it, you can launch a simple APACHE server with php5 via

`$ php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/your/application`

Otherwise, you'll need to change the path to your stylesheet in each of your html files since they are all nested at different levels.

For instance, your `index.html` would have a link tag in its head with a path of `css/style.css`, whereas your `/projects/somepage.html` will have a link tag in its head with a path of `../css/style.css`.

With that said, if you're serious about building web sites you **need** to learn to use development servers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra '/' in front of css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

Should work just fine. I think with the extra /, it's trying look another folder up.. into nothing. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<link href="./css/style.css" />
```

Or

```
<link href="css/style.css" />
```

By just having the slash it is trying to look in the site root. By adding the period it is looking in the document's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Such urls (site root-relative, the ones starting with slash) can't be properly resolved when opening file locally (using file:// protocol) - the browser will search for these files in your system root (C:/). You need using remote configuration (access your html using the web server url rather than local path) to make this work. Note that Idea supports so-called built-in webserver (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/built-in+web+server), so you can test your code without installing a web server. And as of Idea 13 there is only one run configuration for JS debugging, and the run configuration created from right-click menu  (action "Create/Debug" html file) uses the url on built-in http server instead of file url